# How to write function to alter a string and also do arithmetic

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a variable in a dataframe that contains values that either say `Varies with device` or `a number with M` after, or `a number with k` after.

For example:

```
10M
1.2M
120k
Varies with device
```

I want to take `the values with M` and simply delete the `M` and I want to take `the values with k` and delete the `k` and also multiple them by 0.001.

Examples output:

```
10
1.2
0.12
Varies with device
```

I want the output to be in a variable in the `dataframe`, either replacing the original variable, or as a new one.

I tried to create a function like this, but I can't get it to work.

```
convert <- function(x) {
  if(grep("M$", x)) {
  str_sub(x, 1, -1)
  as.numeric(x)
  } else if(grep("k$", x)) {
    str_sub(x, 1, -1)
    as.numeric(x)
    (x*0.001)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did a few adjustments to your funtion. It should now work propertly.

```
convert <- function(x) {
  if(length(grep("M$", x)) > 0) {
    x <- str_sub(x, 1, nchar(x)-1)
    as.numeric(x)
  } else if(length(grep("k$", x)) > 0) {
    x <- str_sub(x, 1, nchar(x)-1)
    as.numeric(x)*0.001
  } else {
    x
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me how to edit it! However it is turning the "Varies with device" into NA and while it does remove the "M" and "k", it does not multiply the "k" values as it should. Any ideas on what I can do to make it work?

Comment: Hmm it works on my machine... Have you any whitespaces in the strings, e.g. "120M "... The str_sub function would then not delete the M but just the white space.

Comment: It seems to be deleting the M's and the k's but it just doesn't multiply the numbers attached to k by 0.001. And it turns the other values in NAs...

Comment: Apply the funktion like this: `df$var_converted <- sapply(df$var_unconverted, convert)`

Answer (score 1):

```
test <- c("10M 1.2M 120k Varies with device")

library(stringr)
library(magrittr)

str_replace_all(test,"[0-9\\.]+(?=k)",function(x){as.numeric(x)/1000}) %>%
  gsub("k|M","",.)

[1] "10 1.2 0.12 Varies with device"
```

The function `str_replace_all` replace a matched pattern by an other pattern, or by the matched pattern transformed by a function. I use it here to divide per 1000 the numbers `[0-9\\.]+` followed by k `(?=k)`.

I then remove the k and M with gsub (I matche k or M `"k|M"` and replace it with nothing)

It works with a vector too

```
test <- c("10M","1.2M", "120k"," Varies with device")
str_replace_all(test,"[0-9\\.]+(?=k)",function(x){as.numeric(x)/1000}) %>%
   gsub("k|M","",.)

[1] "10"                  "1.2"                 "0.12"                " Varies with device"
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems to work with the test data but not with mine. The only thing it does wrong is all the values that have "k" become NA. Do you have any idea why that would be happening? For example, "201k" became NA.

Comment: It works for me, even with "201k". Did you load `library(stringr)` ? Could you reproduce your problem with an example and edit your question ?